# The probability of exactly one periodic event occurring in a timeframe

Tags: probability

Given a periodic event with period $d$, I'm interested in determining whether *exactly one* event will occur within a time frame, say $[t_0, t_1)$.

A few truths jump out at me:

- If $d < \frac{\Delta t}{2}$, this is impossible, as at least 2 events will necessarily occur.
- If $d = \Delta t$, exactly 1 event will occur within this time frame, with probability 1.

From here, I tried to figure out the  probability of the 2 remaining cases.  I came up with:

- $Pr = \frac{2d - \Delta t}{d}$ for $\frac{\Delta t}{2} \le d < \Delta t$, and
- $Pr = \frac{\Delta t}{d}$ for $\Delta t < d$.

And then from there, I somehow arrived at

$$Pr = \max\left(0,~1 - \left|\frac{\Delta t - d}{d}\right|\right) $$

I'm not convinced these deductions are correct in the first place, let alone the correct way to approach the problem.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

*PS.  One way to think about this problem is a camera placed over a bowling alley.  You know that the bowling ball will be in the the camera's FOV between $t_0$ and $t_1$, and you know the camera takes pictures with an inter-capture delay of $d$.  What is the probability the camera takes exactly one picture of the ball.*

*PPS. I'm not very familiar with the math SE, so tag edits / suggestions are very welcome.*

Comment: To discuss probability, you have to have some probabilistic event in mind. What is the random variable here? The period appears to be fixed. Is the start of the time interval random? Is the length or end of the time interval random? What is the distribution of the random variable(s)?

Comment: @MPW, the period is indeed fixed.  The start of the time interval doesn't seem consequential, as one should get the same answer if we shift everything back $n \times d$ seconds.  What you might say is random is the "offset" of the periodic occurrence.  For example, an occurrence with period $d=2$ may occur at 0,2,4,6,... or 1,3,5,7,... (or 0.5, 2.5, 4.5, ..., etc.)  And if that answers you question about what is random, then its distribution would be uniform over $d$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach this problem using Poisson process.
Consider an event occurs with a periodicity $\lambda$ events/time-unit. Then What is the probability that an event will occur between $[t_0,t_1)$

Considering $t_0 = 0$, we can have $\lambda' = \lambda \times t_1$ as the new periodicity.
Then, Probability that you have exactly one event during this time is
$$P(N=1) = \frac{e^{-t_1}(t_1)}{1!}$$

(This is following standard definition of Poisson Process. I have to rush, there might be some issues which I will see after I return from my meeting.)

Comment: The problem is about a process that is actually periodic, not about one that is probabilistic with a fixed mean time of arrival per last event.