# Probability of periodic event happening within time period

Tags: probability

If my web page loses connection every 20 minutes and wipes out a form that takes 15 minutes to fill out what is the probability (odds) that I will get a form filled out and submitted without being interrupted? My best-worst guess is 1-(15/20) or 25% on the basis that there is a 15/20 percent chance I will get interrupted.

Maybe: [The probability of exactly one periodic event occurring in a timeframe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962571/the-probability-of-exactly-one-periodic-event-occurring-in-a-timeframe)  but no accepted answer there.

Comment: You need to make some assumption on the distribution.  Your answer would be correct on the (unlikely) assumption that the thing shuts down regularly every $20$ minutes.  A more plausible assumption would be that there is a Poisson distribution here, or that the thing loses connection each minute with independent probability $\frac 1{20}$.

Comment: Note;  I suggest doing it both ways (binomial and Poisson).  The answers should be very close and you check them against each other.

Comment: Well, actually the current sign-in times out every 20 minutes and asks the user to sign in again and reloads the page, so yes, periodically. So, 25% is actually correct?

Comment: Really?  But then you need to assume that you start the task at a uniformly random point in the $20$ minute window.  If that is also true, then I agree with the $25\%$ since you need to start the form within $5$ minutes of sign in.  But is that a plasuible assumption?

Comment: Consider this a Dilbert problem. Yes, that actually is the case. Yes, I guess the short answer is the user will learn to finish the form within the next 20 minute interruption. I didn't write the system, I'm just trying to argue that even though having to sign in again every 20 minutes hasn't been a problem it's because they have never given a user any form to fill out never mind a form that takes 15 minutes. I thought I would throw some math at them - always the best counter to an appeal to tradition fallacy. "Well, there is only a 25% chance the user will be able to submit the form."

Comment: Well, under those assumptions your solution looks good.  To be fair, we can make it less artificial, if, say, we imagine that some internal setting (of which the user is unaware) is on a $20$ minute schedule and that the user's start time is entirely independent of this cycle.